# XML without LF and CR

Tags: xml

I am new to this and not a pc programmer, we are use to receive orders as .xml with LF and CR but recently the file as been strip from those leaving us with a .xml that look like one long record.
I found a way to convert but it is long and %?&$.  is there a way in simple pc code that I can use to convert back those .xml  with the Pretty print thing (LF and CR) and file will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                    
 <order>                                                                   
  <buyer-accepts-marketing type=" ">true</buyer-accepts-marketing>  
  <closed-at type="" nil="true"></closed-at>                      
  <created-at type="">2009-09-22T18:20:25-04:00</created-at>      
  <currency>USD</currency>'
```

thank you so much

Comment: if you add a tag indicating what platform you are using (.net, java, php, perl, mumps, whatever) you would get more views and more relevant answers.

Answer (score -1):

What is `pc code`? Is it okay for you to use a utility like Notepad++ and install the XML Tools extension which allows you to pretty-print the XML file? There are also online tools you could use: http://xmlprettyprint.com/